# lightbox binding problem on javascript call

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I have one function of java-script which is adding content to my HTML page. Also I have light box script added on that page. Now when i am calling light-box function after page load light box script is working fine but when I call that java script function which is appending HTML to my page then on click of the content of added HTML light-box is not working.What should I do

my code is like this

```
function add_new_block()
{
    strnew='<div>\n 
                <div class="normal_red">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return add_new_block();">Add more</a>
                </div>
                <a href="ajax_show_specific.php?subcat_id=1&catid=2" class="lbOn">Be More Specific</a>
           </div>';

    document.getElementById("newdiv"+(newcount-1)+subcatid).innerHTML=strnew;
}
```

> **Thanks for Help in Advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because the new elements are binded to the DOM and so the lightbox script can't "see" them.  Do you have some initialisation script for the lightbox?  Something like `initLightbox()`?  If so add that to the end of your `add_new_block();` function.